# What Project SDK should I use when creating an sbt project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

If I don't set the Project SDK setting, I get a warning in the IDE. Do I need the Java JDK for a Scala SBT project?

Comment: Now when you didn't chose *Project SDK* can you compile you project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just set it to the newest JDK.